# Using document.getElementById with partial ID name

Tags: javascript, css

Hope you can help me with this problem... My code:

```
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("gatewayContainerstacks_in_9_page4").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 2500); // after 2.5 sec
```

I want to hide a div after 2.5 sec. It is working fine but the problem is that the div I want to target is dynamic. Only the first word is always the same (gatewayContainerstacks). After that the ID is dynamic (the _in_9_page4 part). Is there a way to make the code search out the div starting with gatewayContainerstacks? I would appreciate a hint.. Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) in conjunction with the [CSS attribute selector `^=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match elements with IDs starting with the desired prefix:

```
function showIt() {
  document.querySelector('[id^="gatewayContainerstacks"]').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
setTimeout(showIt, 2500);
```

Here, I also passed the function `showIt` as such (and *not* as a string) to `setTimeout`. See [MDN on `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for the reasons.

Comment: What if the term searched for is in the middle, and not the beginning, of the id?

Comment: @Rodrigo You can use the [CSS attribute selector `*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match for string containment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, you should NEVER pass a string to `setTimeout`. In this case, you can just pass `showIt` (no parentheses!) and it'll work just fine.

As for your actual problem, you can try something like this:

```
document.querySelector("[id^=gatewayContainerstacks]").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

However keep in mind that this will not work in Internet Explorer before version 8, and may not work in some older mobile browsers either.

For a more general solution, I'd suggest giving a unique and known ID, and then putting other information into `data-*` attributes:

```
<div id="gatewayContainerstacks" data-in="9" data-page="4">...</div>
```

Or something like that.